# Adjust screen brightness (hardware) based on context

Tags: windows, automation, display

e.g. Set screen brightness to 50% when running a game or
to 30% when watching a youtube video or
to 0% after 6pm.

Hardware brightness (so the actual brightness of the LED's in the display, not software brightness which just washes the colour out) is adjustable through a program called [ScreenBright](https://github.com/adarshrya/ScreenBright) and it has a command line interface.

So I'm looking for a program that can monitor when I program is run or when certain content is being output to the screen and then trigger a batch file with the required commands for brightness.

Task Scheduler doesn't seem able to do this, although it would manage the last example as it's time based.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way using the above mentioned program and batch file along with a program called Bills Process Manager. It picks up on the process that the program creates and then you can trigger the batch file with it. You can also have it run another batch file when the process ends to set the brightness to a lower level.

Another way to quickly alter the brightness is using the same batch files but with a key combo with AutoHotKey.

The batch file simply has the line:
`C:\ScreenBright\ScreenBright -set brightness 50`

You can also use the function "save" to save the brightness level to the monitor if you want it to remember it when switched off and on.

Comment: Don't forget that you can accept your own answer, which will help others in future